# How to retrieve the id of the last inserted row when using PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Example: I insert a row into the DB with this, using PHP's built in PDO:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, ok) VALUES ('john', '1')";
$this->dbh->exec($sql);
```

I need the id of that row. How could I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `id` is an `auto_increment`, you can use [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) :

> Returns the ID of the last inserted
>   row, or the last value from a sequence
>   object, depending on the underlying
>   driver.

So, in your case, something like this should do the trick :

```
$lastId = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
```