# PDO - get current inserted ID

Tags: php, pdo

```
$query = "INSERT INTO news VALUES (NULL, :param1 , :param2  )";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

$params = array(
    "param1" => $p['title'],
    "param2" => $p['body'],
);

$data = $stmt->execute($params);

// here i would like get current inserted ID. Is possible?

$id = $data->id ???? ;
```

How can i make this?

Comment: Check this -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961471/how-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-row-when-using-pdo-in-php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO news VALUES (NULL, :param1 , :param2  )";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

$params = array(
    "param1" => $p['title'],
    "param2" => $p['body'],
);

$data = $stmt->execute($params);
```

so you can do like this to get last inserted Id

```
$last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: last insert Id seems to imply a possible race condition.  If there are two PDO statements happening at the same time, is there a possibility that the lastInsertId might return the id from the other insert statement?

Answer (score 4):

Use :

```
$last_insert_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
$last_insert_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```