# How to insert same value into to tables sql, php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

can someone help me with this, Im using a simple form to add user into a database, my goal is to add the user into one table, but at the same time add the (userid) into a different table, the user id is made automatically by the database, it is possible to do this ?

Thank you

```
 <?php 
    require("coneccion.php"); 

    if(!empty($_POST))
    { 

      $query = "INSERT INTO students (fname, lname, studentcode) values (:fname, :lname, :studentcode)";
      $query_params = array(':fname' => $_POST['fname'], ':lname' => $_POST['lname'], ':studentcode' => $_POST['studentcode']);

      try
      {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
      }
      catch(PDOException $ex)
      {
        die("Error" . $ex->getMessage());
      }
      $name = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
      $id = $_SESSION['courseid'];
      $query = "INSERT INTO idtables(courseid, studentid) values ('$id', (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$name'))";
      try
      {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
      }
      catch(PDOExecute $ex)
      {
        die("Error" . $ex->getMessage());
      }
      $id = $_SESSION['courseid'];
      header("Location: index.php?id=$id");
      die("Rendirecting to index.php?id=$id");

    }
    ?>

    <?php
    $id = $_SESSION['courseid'];
    echo $id;
    ?>

    <form action="add.php" method="post">
      First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value=""><br>
      Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value=""><br>
      Stude Code: <input type="text" name="studentcode" value=""><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Student">
    </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the id of the last inserted row when using PDO in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961471/how-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-row-when-using-pdo-in-php)

Comment: @Barmar nop is not duplicate

Comment: What's different about your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id of the row you added like this :

```
$studentId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

See [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I try this query  $query = "INSERT INTO idtables(courseid, studentid) values ('$id', (SELECT studentid FROM students WHERE $studentId = $db->lastInsertId();))"; but i gt an error  that says " Undefined property: PDO::$lastInsertId in

Comment: No ... you must do this after the first query is executed. And then you don't need to use a subquery inside the second query. A simple "INSERT INTO idtables (courseid, studentid) VALUES ($id, $studentId);" should do.

Comment: You can't call functions inside a string, you can only substitute variables. You have to call the function, assign the result to a variable, and then you can use the variable in the string. You can also use the MySQL function `last_insert_id()` in your second query.

Comment: Thank i find out how to do it second before I way your commet :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe just to find the student ID by checking names. Does your table structure allow two students with the same name?
Above all you need to make sure that your students table is set with a studentid column that is the primary key and is AUTOINCREMENT. Then you use lastInsertId() and you don't need to do another SELECT in the second (insert) query at all. Just this:

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO students (fname, lname, studentcode) values (:fname, :lname, :studentcode)";
  $query_params = array(':fname' => $_POST['fname'], ':lname' => $_POST['lname'], ':studentcode' => $_POST['studentcode']);

  try
  {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    if($result) $newStudentID = $db->lastInsertId();
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
    die("Error" . $ex->getMessage());
  }
  $name = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
  $id = $_SESSION['courseid'];
  $query = "INSERT INTO idtables(courseid, studentid) values ('$id', $newStudentID)";
```

Comment: yes it allows multiple user with the same name, that's why im trying to use the id to identify, thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

Change the second query to:

```
      $query = "INSERT INTO idtables(courseid, studentid) values ('$id', LAST_INSERT_ID())";
```

[`LAST_INSERT_ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is a built-in MySQL function that returns the last inserted ID.