# on click button inserting user ID into mysql database

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a question and answer application. I have created on click buttons, which the user can use to answer the question. When I click these buttons, the answer goes into the database. I am trying to also get the ID of the user into the database at the same time when the user answers the question.

Below is my code for **abc.php** (the page the where the buttons are):

```
<input type="radio" name="response" value="A">A<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="response" value="B">B<br/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="response" value="C">C<br/><br/>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
<br/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        var response = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { response: response },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});    
</script>
```

**insert.php**

```
if (isset($_POST["response"])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO response(response) VALUES (:response)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array(':response' => $_POST["response"]));
    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "Your answer has been submitted!";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: To clarify: Are you trying to get the ID column of the inserted row and return as the response of the `POST` call? Or you're trying to pass the user ID in the body of the request? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Basically, I want to get the ID of the user and put it into the response table. It is the studentid, which is a foreign key in the response table. So when the user logs in using their studentid, and answers the question, their studentid should go into the response table as a foreign key, so that i can see which student has answered the question

Comment: Have you checked [last_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/ertrefman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html) ? It gets the last inserted id in a mysql connection

Comment: if(isset($_POST["response"]))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO response(response) VALUES (:response)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
    array(
    ':response' => $_POST["response"]
    )
        );
    $query = " INSERT INTO response (student_id)
SELECT studentid
FROM student
WHERE studentid = '".$_SESSION['studentid']."'";
 $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
    
        );

Comment: I have now written the above code but now i can only get the studentid in and the actual response doesnt go in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the id of the last inserted row when using PDO in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961471/how-to-retrieve-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-row-when-using-pdo-in-php)